# Optimizing WER (Word Error Rate) code?

Tags: python, performance, text, nlp

I am trying to compute WER to evaluate an ASR system, but the computation of the score takes a lot of time (since I want to perform some bootstraps on it in order to get confidence intervals for a more robust evaluation of the system).

Here is the code I've come up with so far, does anyone see a more efficient way to do it (faster, and if you have ideas to make it more memory efficient, that would also be welcome).

```
def modify_text(text):
    """
    Function to modify a clean text to add some errors in it.
    """
    modified_text = []
    for word in true_text:
        action = np.random.choice(['deletion','addition','subsitution','nothing'],
                                   p = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.7])
        if action in ['addition','substitution']:
            modified_text.append(random.choice(voca))
        if action in ['addition','nothing']:
            modified_text.append(word)
    return modified_text

def wer(s1,s2):

    d = np.zeros([len(s1)+1,len(s2)+1])
    d[:,0] = np.arange(len(s1)+1)
    d[0,:] = np.arange(len(s2)+1)

    for j in range(1,len(s2)+1):
        for i in range(1,len(s1)+1):
            if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
                d[i,j] = d[i-1,j-1]
            else:
                d[i,j] = min(d[i-1,j]+1, d[i,j-1]+1, d[i-1,j-1]+1)

    return d[-1,-1]/len(s1)

text = """I am happy to join with you today in what will go down in history as
the greatest demonstration for freedom in the history of our nation.
Five score years ago, a great American, in whose symbolic shadow
we stand today, signed the Emancipation Proclamation. This momentous
decree came as a great beacon light of hope to millions of Negro slaves
who had been seared in the flames of withering injustice. It came as a
joyous daybreak to end the long night of their captivity. """

true_text = list(tokenize(text))
modified_text = modify_text(true_text)
%timeit wer(true_text,modified_text)
```

Output:

```
7.04 ms ± 49.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Ok this doesn't seem too bad, but I have tens of thousands of texts to evaluate on, with bootstraps, and the texts are way longer. Therefore, I would like to find a faster way to do the wer function. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Most speech recognition evaluations first segment the speech into sentences or utterances. Then you compute the WER by aligning each utterance. This can give you a big speedup because the WER computation is O(n^2).

Comment: I've seen this in papers, but I see two main problems with this: whait if the sentences aren't independant (for instance an addition at the end of a sentence which corresponds to the first word of the following sentence)? And what if the segmentation in the output of the ASR isn't correctly done? (e.g. one original sentence products two sentences via the ASR)

Comment: If your sentence segmentation model is bad then that will obviously hurt your word error rate.

Comment: Would you have an idea of a robust segmentation model? Because it doesn't seem right that the WER skyrockets just because the ASR can't segment the sentences correctly.

Comment: Well if you want your evaluation to not depend on the sentence segmentation model you can use the ground truth segmentation.

Comment: That would work on the reference, but how can I align this ground truth segmentation to the hypothesis? If the alignment mismatches, I will end up with a biased WER won't I?

Comment: If you have the ground truth sentence boundaries and timestamps then you can use ground truth sentence segmentation when comparing the hypothesized word sequence against the ground truth word sequence

Answer (score 0):

Good to try jiwer package. It does take care of some data cleaning and transformation as well (please see https://github.com/jitsi/jiwer). It works for me for a medium size of data; it needs to be checked for large data.

Some codes to calculate errors:

```
    import jitwer 
    ground_truth = "ground truth text"
    modified_text = "modified text or output of model to ground truth text" 
    
    # list of transformations you can apply on your text data
    transformation = jiwer.Compose([
        jiwer.ToLowerCase(),
        jiwer.Strip(),
        jiwer.RemoveEmptyStrings(),
        jiwer.RemoveMultipleSpaces(),
        jiwer.RemoveWhiteSpace(replace_by_space=False),
        jiwer.SentencesToListOfWords(word_delimiter=" "),
        jiwer.ExpandCommonEnglishContractions(),
        jiwer.RemoveKaldiNonWords()
    ]) 

    wer = jiwer.wer(
        ground_truth, 
        modified_text, 
        truth_transform=transformation, 
        hypothesis_transform=transformation
    )
    mer = jiwer.mer(
        ground_truth, 
        modified_text, 
        truth_transform=transformation, 
        hypothesis_transform=transformation
    )
    wil = jiwer.wil(
        ground_truth, 
        modified_text, 
        truth_transform=transformation, 
        hypothesis_transform=transformation
    )
    measures = jiwer.compute_measures(ground_truth, modified_text)
```